# Javascript object not appending new attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, javascript-objects

I have this function, where I retrieve an array of objects, I then have a for loop to loop through the objects, and append an index or ind attribute to it:

```
module.exports.getCustomers = async (req, res) => {
  let customers = await Customers.find({}, { "_id": 1 });

  for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
    customers[i].ind = i;
  }

  console.log(customers)
}
```

but when I run this, the data is returned as

```
[
  { _id: ... },
  { _id: ... },
  ...
]
```

instead of:

```
[
   {_id: ..., ind: 0},
   {_id: ..., ind: 1},
   ...
]
```

Please how do I fix this

Comment: Have you tried `Object.assign`?

Comment: theres nothing wrong with the code provided can you give us more information on  Customers.find()

Comment: try this: `await Customers.find({}, { "_id": 1 }).toArray();`

Comment: Can you please provide the value of `await Customers.find({}, { "_id": 1 })`? So that it will easier to provide a solution.

Comment: `Customers.update(
            { _id: 1 },
            { ind: '...' },
            { multi: true },
            function (err, num) {
            });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `Customers.find()` [returns a cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find), you will [find here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#read-operations-cursors) how to properly use it

Comment: you could add an `ind` field in your `Customers` schema

Comment: Are you using mongoose?

Comment: @Anthony Winzlet  yes i am

Comment: Then use [`.lean()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)

Comment: @Anthony Winzlet where and how ?

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 2):

change your `for` and turn it into a `map`

```
module.exports.getCustomers = async (req, res) => {
  let customers = await Customers.find({}, { "_id": 1 });

  let mappedCustomers = customers.map((customer, index) => {
              customer['ind'] = index;
              return customer;
          });


  console.log(mappedCustomers);
  return mappedCustomers;
}
```

or instead returning the customer, you can create a completly new customer.

```
let mappedCustomers = customers.map((customer, index) => {
              return {...customer, ind: index};
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your objects are freezed, idk what library you are using to fetch those items from your data source, but you can read about object freezing here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

Comment: Question is tagged [tag:mongodb]

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the values over to the individual target objects with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```
module.exports.getCustomers = async(req, res) => {
  let customers = await Customers.find({}, {
    "_id": 1
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
    Object.assign(customers[i], {
      ind: i
    });
  }

  console.log(customers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. I think `mongoose` was messing with it. But adding `._doc` seems to have fixed it

```
for (let i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {

    let customer = customers[i], 

    customer._doc = {
      ...customer._doc,
      index: i
    };
}
```